# Better way of defining Context object

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I wanted to use the entity framework context object every time.
What could be the better way to define in asp.net?

ex:

```
using(employeeEntities context = new employeeEntities ())
    {

    }
```

I want to use this context every where without reusing the `using`

Comment: Related: [Entity Framework 4 ObjectContext Lifetime](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3362280/87698)

Comment: Please define everywhere? Everywhere in a class? In your whole project?

Answer (score 3):

While you can do that microsoft recommends using the context in a different way, take a look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738470%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
...
The lifetime of the ObjectContext begins when the instance is created and ends when the instance is either disposed or garbage-collected. Use using if you want all the resources that the context controls to be disposed at the end of the block. When you use using, the compiler creates a try/finally block and calls dispose in the finally block. Here are some general guidelines when deciding on the lifetime of the object context:

1. When working with long-running object context consider the following:
 - As you load more objects and their references into memory, the object
   context may grow quickly in memory consumption. This may cause

   performance issues.
 - Remember to dispose of the context when it is no longer required.
 - If an exception caused the object context to be in an unrecoverable
   state, the whole application may terminate.
 - The chances of running into concurrency-related issues increase as
   the gap between the time when the data is queried and updated grows.

2. When working with Web applications, **use an object context instance per request**... 

3. When working with Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) or Windows Forms, use an object context instance per form. This lets you use change tracking functionality that object context provides. 
...
```

In addition take a look at this related thread: [One DbContext per web request... why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585478/one-dbcontext-per-web-request-why)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want some syntax sugar to avoid using `using` but still create a new context every time, You can write some extension methods which help you write code like this:

```
// Execute is the extension method which takes the code 
// in the using block as a delegate
SomeEntities.Execute(context => 
    context.SomeTable.Where(item => item.Ammount > 100));
```

I can share you the code if that's what you want. Refer to CloudyMarble's answer if you want to use a single context all the time.